# Save float values in SQL Server

Tags: c#, sql, sql-server-2005, floating-point

I have a simple web app , and want to save some numbers of Float or Double format in SQL server.

but there is a problem , when I try to save 123.66 , In Table I see 123.6600003662109 stored.

How nd why my float number changed when save on DB? how can I fix this error?

Thanks

Answer (score 16, accepted):

You're not *actually* trying to save 123.66, because you can't represent 123.66 exactly as a float or double. The database is saving the data more accurately than you're used to, that's all.

If you want to save *decimal* numbers accurately, use the `decimal` type.

See my articles on [floating binary point](http://pobox.com/~skeet/csharp/floatingpoint.html) and [floating decimal point](http://pobox.com/~skeet/csharp/decimal.html) types for more info.

Answer (score 4):

This is not a database issue, but a [general problem with floating numbers](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Floating_point#Accuracy_problems)

Answer (score 0):

I think this is VS Problem not Sql server,
Here i pass amount in string ("12.89") to stored procedure and find data save accurate 12.89

### Solution-

Change Float to string in Properties and Methods,procedure

Note

### don't change column type Float to string  in table

Example-

### In Your Property

```
Public Float Amount { get; set; }
```

TO

```
Public String Amount { get; set; }
```

### In Your Method

```
Public boolAdd(String amount)

{

//Your Logic Like

bool status = false;

DbParam[] param = new DbParam[1];

param[0] = new DbParam("@amount", "", "amount", SqlDbType.VarChar);

status = Db.Update(ds, "sp_Add", "", "", param, true);

return status;

  }
```

### In Your  Procedure

### Note- Amount column is Float type in table don't change to sting

---

```
Create Proc sp_Add
(

@amount varchar(20)

)
as

begin

Insert into Price(amount) values (@amount)

end
```

Comment: Please edit your answer to fix the code formatting. Have a read of the guide on how to do this.