# how to rounding the numbers after decimal point?

Tags: java, sql-server

Hi Am developing one application in java and Am using sql server database . I'm inserting values in database in 23.6 but its appending like 23.645464 . is there any method to append after decimal no only one digit. please help me.

Thanks

Comment: Try editing the table structure so that the target field only holds one decimal place.

Comment: Possible duplicate: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1005725/save-float-values-in-sql-server

Comment: check this 
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/153724/how-to-round-a-number-to-n-decimal-places-in-java

Answer (score 0):

how about this in sql server.

```
SELECT round (cast(23.645464 AS DECIMAL(10,1)),2);
```

Answer (score 0):

Hey you can try this code in Java file before storing value in database..

For example :

Function call :

```
float round = Round(num,1);
```

Definition:

```
public static float Round(float val, int dec) {
  float p = (float)Math.pow(10,dec);
  val = val * p;
  float tmp = Math.round(val);
  return (float)tmp/p;
  }
```