# SQL - Float number appears as XE-05

Tags: sql, sql-server, number-formatting

I am inserting float numbers in Microsoft SQL and some of them appears as:

```
7E-05
5E-05
6E-05
```

The other float are inserted as expected. 
For example this float `0.00007` is inserted as `7E-05` but this one `0.01500` as `0.015`.

I was suspecting the size of float but after reducing it to x.yyyyy I still get this kind of float.
Anyone know what causing this issue?

Comment: Where do they appear that way?  Floats in SQL (and C#) are just numbers, so the actual _value_ appears to be stored correctly. (I'm assuming that you understand that `7E-05` and `0.00007` are the same number)

Comment: in the SQL. When I SELECT the value, I get the 7E-05 instead of 0.00007. It's important to show to the client the 0.0007 value.

Comment: Then format it when you show it to the client - in the report, app, Excel, whatever.  I'm assuming your client is not running a SQL query?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you want to store values like this, use `DECIMAL` instead of `FLOAT` in following: `DECIMAL(18,5)` It will allow your to store number with 5 digits after `,`

**Sample:**

```
CREATE TABLE #test
(
    ID DECIMAL(18,5)
)
INSERT INTO #Test VALUES (0.00007)

SELECT ID FROM #Test

DROP TABLE #Test
```

Result:

```
0.00007
```

---

As *Jon Skeet* said:

> You're not actually trying to save 123.66, because you can't represent
>   123.66 exactly as a float or double. The database is saving the data more accurately than you're used to, that's all.
>
> If you want to save decimal numbers accurately, use the decimal type.

---

You can read more at:
<kbd>[Link 1](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1056323/difference-between-numeric-float-and-decimal-in-sql-server)</kbd>
<kbd>[Link 2](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1005725/save-float-values-in-sql-server)</kbd>
<kbd>[Link 3](http://jonskeet.uk/csharp/decimal.html)</kbd>
<kbd>[Link 4](http://jonskeet.uk/csharp/floatingpoint.html)</kbd>

Comment: The problem is not the data type - it's the _display_ of the data.  `Decimal` has no better capability to store 0.00007 that `float` does

Comment: Hi and thanks for your answer.Actually numeric(18,5) solve this issue which I applied before posting the question here on a wrong field. So I applied on the correct now and it works ok.

Comment: @DStanley yes, It is noticed in links which I provided. Here is solution how to store values like this `0.00007` (as `DECIMAL`) into table and after select It.